# Sending linux commands in Perl - Grep piped to grep

Tags: linux, perl, grep, command, pipe

The basic code:

```
my $ContentDate = `date -d '1 hour ago' '+%Y-%m-%e %H:'`;
my $Fail2banNo = `grep Ban /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep $ContentDate | wc -l`;

if (($Fail2banNo > $fail2ban)) {

} else {

}
```

Why wont Perl complete these commands correctly? $fail2ban is already defined to 0, so that's not the issue.

The fail2ban.log does contain a line that should match(when running command from shell it matches):

```
2018-07-19 xx:11:50,200 fail2ban.actions[3725]: WARNING [iptables] Ban x.x.x.x
```

The error i keep getting is:

```
grep: 10:: No such file or directory
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
sh: -c: line 1: ` | wc -l'
Argument "" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at /usr/local/bin/tmgSupervision.pl line 3431.
```

All the commands run fine from bash/shell, seems at if perl is not happy with grep being piped to another grep? I've tried many different ways of adding the variable($ContentDate) into the grep without helping.

Comment: try `grep '$ContentDate'` as the variable has spaces in it... without the quotes, grep would see two arguments and try to treat the second one as filename

Comment: Then the grep is not working properly, getting results for a totally different date: 2018-07-18 09:11:50,200. So the whole $ContentDate is not being utilized. Tried running chomp on the different variables to remove newline, resultet in another error.

Comment: Why do you use external commands for this anyway? Doing it all natively in Perl will offer you a lot more control over what you are doing, and will be more efficient, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I notice that the answer you've accepted has a rather over-complicated way to calculate the timestamp an hour ago, so I present this alternative which uses Perl's built-in date and time handling in a more efficient manner.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

my $log = '/var/log/fail2ban.log';
my $fail2ban = 0;

my $ContentDate = localtime(time - 3600)->strftime('%Y-%m-%e %H:');
my $Fail2banNo = qx{grep Ban $log | grep "$ContentDate" | wc -l};

if ($Fail2banNo > $fail2ban) {
  say 'Yes';
}
else {
  say 'No';
}
```

But the only change you actually needed was to change:

```
my $Fail2banNo = `grep Ban /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep $ContentDate | wc -l`;
```

to:

```
my $Fail2banNo = `grep Ban /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep "$ContentDate" | wc -l`;
```

Quoting `$ContentDate` because it contains a space.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Cross for the Time::Piece very usefull

Comment: Time::Piece is one of the hardest modules to use correctly, and completely unnecessary here. `use POSIX; strftime('%Y-%m-%e %H:', localtime(time - 3600))` would just as fine.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `$ContentDate` ends with a line feed.

The second problem is that you improperly create the shell literal from `$ContentDate` (using `grep 2018-07-19 08:` instead of something like `grep '2018-07-19 08:'`).

Let's first fix your answer.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $fail2ban_log_qfn = '/var/log/fail2ban.log';

my $content_date = `date -d '1 hour ago' '+%Y-%m-%e %H:'`;
chomp($content_date);

my $grep_cmd1 = shell_quote('grep', 'Ban', $fail2ban_log_qfn);
my $grep_cmd2 = shell_quote('grep', '--', $content_date);
my $fail2ban_count = `$grep_cmd1 | $grep_cmd2 | wc -l`;
chomp($fail2ban_count);
```

No need to shell out to get the date, though.

```
use POSIX              qw( strftime );
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $fail2ban_log_qfn = '/var/log/fail2ban.log';

my $content_date = strftime('%Y-%m-%e %H:', localtime(time - 3600));

my $grep_cmd1 = shell_quote('grep', 'Ban', $fail2ban_log_qfn);
my $grep_cmd2 = shell_quote('grep', '--', $content_date);
my $fail2ban_count = `$grep_cmd1 | $grep_cmd2 | wc -l`;
chomp($fail2ban_count);
```

No need to shell out to to count the matching lines either.

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $fail2ban_log_qfn = '/var/log/fail2ban.log';

my $fail2ban_count = 0;
{
   my $content_date = strftime('%Y-%m-%e %H:', localtime(time - 3600));

   open(my $fh, '<', $log_qfn)
      or die("Can't open \"$fail2ban_log_qfn\": $!\n");

   while (<$fh>) {
      ++$fail2ban_count if /Ban/ && /\Q$content_date/;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $log = "/var/log/fail2ban.log";
my $fail2ban = 0;

my $ContentDate = backintime(3600); #backintime in seconds from now
my $Fail2banNo = qx{grep Ban $log | grep \"$ContentDate\"| wc -l};

if ($Fail2banNo > $fail2ban) {
        say "Yes";
}
else {
        say "No";

}


sub backintime {
        my ($to_today) = @_;
        my $temps = time - 60*60*24*0;
        $temps = $temps - $to_today;
        my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime($temps);
        if($sec < 10) {$sec = "0" . $sec;}
        if($min < 10) {$min = "0" . $min;}
        if($hour < 10) {$hour = "0" . $hour;}
        if($mday < 10) {$mday = "0" . $mday;}
        $year+=1900; $mon++; if($mon < 10) {$mon = "0" . $mon;}
        my $sectime = $year."-".$mon."-".$mday." ".$hour.":";
        return($sectime);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, that's a much better way of doing it! Working fine now :D

Comment: Can I suggest you take a look at [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) :-)

Comment: `my $temps = time - 60*60*24*0` Why are you subtracting zero?

Comment: it has been done in a loop without any module: here 0 equal today, 1 equal yesterday, 2 equal day before yesterday etc..